# Remove mix-blend-mode from child element

Tags: css, background-blend-mode

How can I set mix-blend-mode on an element, but not it's children?  Setting the children to the default value of `normal` does not seem to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/uoq916Ln/1/

Comment: It is the same issue as with opacity. It is not really that the property is inherited, it is that all the block is rendered with this effect

Answer (score 15):

The solution on how to avoid `mix-blend-mode` affects children:

1. Make child element position relative, give it a width and height;
2. Create some real or pseudo element inside the child with absolute position, and apply `mix-blend-mode` to it;
3. Create `inner` element inside the child for your content. Make it's position absolute, and put it on top of other elements;

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/uoq916Ln/10/)

**html**

```
<div class="bkdg">
    <div class="blend">
        <div class="inner">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.blend {
    position: relative; /* Make position relative */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.blend::before { /* Apply blend mode to this pseudo element */
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: green;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.inner { /* This is our content, must have absolute position */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this was asked over two years ago, but it could be useful in the future as it could be a better solution than creating pseudo-elements.

There is the CSS [`isolation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/isolation) property that allows to choose wether the child element should be rendered in its parent's context (`auto`) or as part of a new context, thus without any blend mode applied to it (`isolate`).

Check out [this page](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/isolation/) for examples

Comment: If I'm right isolation only guards siblings of an element against mix-blend-mode. It does not work on children.

Answer (score 4):

someone commented that the the whole block is rendered with the effect and that is why you're having the issue. I am able to accomplish what you're are trying to do by removing the h1 from the block, position absolute, and a z-index of 1. here is a jsfiddle to show the effect.

html

```
<div class="bkdg">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <div class="blend">
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.blend {
    background-color: green;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    width: 700px;
    height: 35px;
}
h1 {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px; left: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jckot1pu/

Comment: Well that is a tough question. While it accomplishes what you want you may not consider this a solution and I can understand that. However in my experience I have found sometimes to accomplish the css styling you want sometimes you have to do things in a round about way.

Answer (score 3):

**It’s impossible to *remove* an element’s `mix-blend-mode` from its children.**

[MDN says](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) that `mix-blend-mode`:

> sets how an element's **content** should blend with the content of the element's parent and the element's background

To achieve the desired effect, place the child in a separate [stacking context](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) and make sure it renders on top of the element with `mix-blend-mode` set.

You need two things to make this work:

- Make sure that your *opaque* content (your text) is not a child of the element that sets the background and the blend mode. For example, with [CSS Grid Layout](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).
- Make sure the text is rendered over, and thus not affected by, the element that sets the background and the blend mode. Setting `mix-blend-mode` on your background will create a stacking context for it, and you may need to give your content its own stacking context to ensure it gets rendered above it.

**Position your elements with CSS Grid:**

- define a grid container with one auto-sized grid area
- place both the background element and the text element into that one grid area (so that they overlap)
- let the text element dictate the size of the grid area
- have the background element stretch to the size of the grid area, which is dictated by the size of the text element

Then, set `isolation: isolate` on the text element to ensure it gets rendered above, and not under the background element.

**A working example**

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'item';
  place-content: end stretch;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/237/400/200);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  grid-area: item;
  background-color: seagreen;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

.item {
  grid-area: item;
  isolation: isolate;
  color: white;
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h1>HEADLINE</h1>
    <p>Subhead</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An important note if you're using the excellent pseudoelement ::before/::after solution posted by Rashad Ibrahimov.

I found that I had to remove z-index from the parent element and apply it only to the pseudoelements and child elements before `mix-blend-mode: multiply` would work.

**For example**

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#wrapper .hoverlabel {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    /* z-index: 90; Uncomment this to break mix-blend-mode. Tested in Firefox 75 and Chrome 81. */
}

#wrapper .hoverlabel::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    z-index: 90;
    background-color: rgba(147, 213, 0, 0.95);
}
```