# Wordpress mix-blend-mode affecting child div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, mix-blend-mode

I'm trying to port a Photoshop mockup into my Wordpress theme. I want the portfolio image to get a *"mixed-blend-mode: multiply layer with a green color"*  on hover.

The H3 text in the child div "vert-center" gets affected by the mix-blend-mode and I can't figure out a way to disable it for this div.

[Image example: 1. no hover PS mockup 2. on hover PS mockup 3. how it looks in my browser right now (with the affected text circled).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3cxq.png)

A similar question [was asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629541/remove-mix-blend-mode-from-child-element) however I haven't been able to solve it with the answer.

**I'm working in Wordpress and adjusting the Custom CSS code in my theme so have limited options to play with.**

**Custom CSS**

```
.work-info:hover { 
background-color: #00e1af;
mix-blend-mode: multiply;
opacity: 1 !important; 
}
```

**The HTML for displaying the portfolio item**

```
<div class="col elastic-portfolio-item  element commercial feed videos" data-project-cat="commercial feed videos " data-default-color="true" data-title-color="" data-subtitle-color="" style="width: 425px; position: absolute; left: 850px; top: 0px;">

                    <div class="inner-wrap" data-animation="none">


                        <div class="work-item style-3-alt" data-custom-content="off" data-text-align="middle">

                            <img class="size- skip-lazy" src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/jj-600x403.png" alt="" height="403" width="600" srcset="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/jj-600x403.png 600w, https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/jj-400x269.png 400w" sizes="(min-width: 1000px) 25vw, (min-width: 690px) 50vw, 100vw" style="height: 285px; background-blend-mode:screen !important;">
                            <div class="work-info-bg"></div>
                            <div class="work-info">

                                <a href="https://vimeo.com/224912269?iframe=true" class="default-link gallery magnific" target="_blank" style="display: inline;"></a>                                   

                                <div class="vert-center">

                                        <h3>Example Portfolio Titel </h3> 


                                </div><!--/vert-center-->

                            </div>
                        </div><!--work-item-->



                </div><!--/inner-wrap-->
                </div>
```

Does someone now if I can fix this with CSS?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried taking .vert-center element out from .work-info and place it in after .work-info element.within .work-item. and you will have to make it a absolute positioned within a relative positioned div. ie: div.work-item.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It is a Wordpress theme so I can't simply move a div out without going into the theme code and see how the page get's generated. However if that is the only way I have to figure it out I guess. Would be better if I could do it using custom css.

Comment: here the problem is you need Mix-blend-mode and at the same time you cannot have your text get effected on hover. I guess you could try this. hope it will work as I do not know the whole html structure above img tag. so just guessing. [.work-info a.gallery.magnific:hover{mix-blend-mode: multiply;} ] instead of whole div.

Comment: When I use "work-info {background-color:red !important;}" I see a change. But using ".work-info a.gallery.magnific:hover{background-color:red !important;}" nothing happens. Is the selector wrong or is there something which makes that element unable to visibly change for example it's background color?

Comment: I ment the mix-blend-mode effect which in this case background color. so I think both or background color alone but without !important. if possible.