# Mix-blend-mode: screen cut-out effect only to div tittle

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website that has a slider and above the swiper, but separated from it (so it does not move on slide) there's an absolute positioned white back-grounded div which contains the tittle of the product and some more info. What I'm trying to do is have the tittle with mix-blend-mode applied so it creates a cut-out effect and looks like text is transparent so you can see the image behind it. Until here everything works fine if I apply the mix-blend-mode: screen to the parent element. The problem comes when I try to add the rest of the info, since it's being modified by the mix-blend-mode of the parent so it's also transparent (which I imagine is the expected behavior).

This is the html structure

```
<div class="divdefault">
 <div class="divdefault wrappedraimgswiper">
  //Here goes some php logic to load images.
  <div class="divdefault pedraimg slide" data-ratio="1.0773">
   <div class="imgpedraprod" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: url(img) no-repeat center center/cover"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="div cuadroinfopedraprod" style="">
  <div class="divdefault titulopedraprod letra52 bold">Tittle</div>
  <div class="divdefault restoinfo">
   <div class="divdefault">rest</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And this is the css for the div I was talking about

```
.div.cuadroinfopedraprod{position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 180px; z-index: 10; background: #fff; padding: 50px 60px 80px 60px; mix-blend-mode: screen}
```

I've already tried taking background out of parent, apply it only to "titulopedraprod" and mix-blend-mode: screen this element.
Also tried using pseudo-elements for background and mix-blend
But none of this seem to work. All I get is titulopedraprod turning white.
I've understand that probably I need to change my html structure, but how could I do it without losing the desired effect of keeping everything in the same box.

[Image with desired effect, which shows background, tittle and first line of text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3omi.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629541/remove-mix-blend-mode-from-child-element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove mix-blend-mode from child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629541/remove-mix-blend-mode-from-child-element)

Comment: The problem with the duplicate answer is that structure is not the same, as my background is not in the div I need to apply the effect or any of it's childs.

Comment: Agreed. I've removed the close vote but the problem is fundamentally the same. You want the mix-blend-mode to affect just one child.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `background-clip: text` or/and a .webp/.svg image with transparency made in a graphic editor of your choice (for example Figma) and invisible divs for clickable elements.

Comment: How or at which element should I apply the background-clip. The problem with the image is that tittle can be anything, since we are talking about products, and I can't generate images for every single product. apart from that I have to keep in mind that client may want to add products in the future which would lead to having to generate more images.