# Exclude logo from being affect by `mix-blend-mode: difference` in header

Tags: html, css, mix-blend-mode

My header contains navigation and a logo. I've set `mix-blend-mode` on the `.header` so as the page is scrolled, the text within the header will change colour depending on the background.

The problem with this is, all the child elements are affected by the `difference` declaration. More importantly the logo, which should maintain the same colour/styling as it has by default.

Is there a way to exclude this for the `mix-blend-mode` property so it doesn't change? I've tried setting a pseudo `:before` / `:after` element behind the logo with absolute positioning to 'block out' the area behind the logo but everything I've tried so far doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this without removing the logo from the `.header` entirely?

I'm under the assumption that the `mix-blend-mode` property needs to be on the top-level parent and applying it to the `nav` alone will not work (which it doesn't).

```css
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 64px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.site-logo svg {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
}

.header ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.header li {
  margin-right: 32px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a href="#" class="site-logo">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" id="Layer_1" x="0" y="0" style="enable-background:new 0 0 64 64" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 64 64"><style>.st0{fill:#fff}</style><path d="M0 0h64v64H0z"/><path d="M9.46 22.06h1.96V35.6h6.49v1.64H9.46V22.06zM29.58 31.7c0 4.03-2.79 5.79-5.43 5.79-2.95 0-5.23-2.16-5.23-5.61 0-3.65 2.39-5.79 5.41-5.79 3.13 0 5.25 2.27 5.25 5.61zm-8.65.11c0 2.39 1.37 4.19 3.31 4.19 1.89 0 3.31-1.78 3.31-4.23 0-1.85-.92-4.19-3.27-4.19-2.34-.01-3.35 2.16-3.35 4.23zM41.47 26.34c-.05.79-.09 1.67-.09 3v6.33c0 2.5-.5 4.03-1.55 4.98-1.06.99-2.59 1.31-3.96 1.31-1.31 0-2.75-.32-3.63-.9l.5-1.51c.72.45 1.85.86 3.2.86 2.03 0 3.51-1.06 3.51-3.81v-1.22h-.05c-.61 1.01-1.78 1.82-3.47 1.82-2.7 0-4.64-2.3-4.64-5.32 0-3.69 2.41-5.79 4.91-5.79 1.89 0 2.93.99 3.4 1.89h.05l.09-1.64h1.73zm-2.05 4.3c0-.34-.02-.63-.11-.9-.36-1.15-1.33-2.09-2.77-2.09-1.89 0-3.24 1.6-3.24 4.12 0 2.14 1.08 3.92 3.22 3.92 1.22 0 2.32-.77 2.75-2.03.11-.34.16-.72.16-1.06v-1.96zM54.54 31.7c0 4.03-2.79 5.79-5.43 5.79-2.95 0-5.23-2.16-5.23-5.61 0-3.65 2.39-5.79 5.41-5.79 3.13 0 5.25 2.27 5.25 5.61zm-8.65.11c0 2.39 1.37 4.19 3.31 4.19 1.89 0 3.31-1.78 3.31-4.23 0-1.85-.92-4.19-3.27-4.19-2.34-.01-3.35 2.16-3.35 4.23z" class="st0"/></svg>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
  </ul>
</header>

<main>
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/18235303/pexels-photo-18235303/free-photo-of-autumn-s-reflection.jpeg">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9367323/pexels-photo-9367323.jpeg">

</main>
```

Comment: You can not "exclude" descendants. If you wanted to fix it by placing something behind the logo - then I guess that would have to be a modified version of the image itself, so that the difference between original and modified one, result in exactly the original image again.

Comment: I would leave the logo where it is, but position it absolutely. Then the `ul` can be made to stretch across the whole header width & height (or you introduce an additional wrapper element, if for some reason you can't do that with the UL itself), and then you apply the `mix-blend-mode` to that, instead of the header itself.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! The layout isn't exactly what I have but just a basic setup to show the two elements. In my actually example there is a `nav` wrapped around the `ul` but applying `mix-blend-mode` to anything other than the `header` doesn't seem to work at all?

Comment: Ah, right, because then you would be blending the content of `nav` with that of `header`, I suppose. Then you might have to take the logo out of the header after all ...

Comment: This question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629541/remove-mix-blend-mode-from-child-element

Comment: Thanks @NickFriesen I gave that ago but couldn't get it to work, I think maybe because my header is transparent and does't have a background-color like in that example ...but I'd be very happy to be wrong!